# Get img tags without width attribute and add inline CSS attribute?

Tags: php

I have a php code that prints some HTML stuff from MYSQL database.

Sometimes there are some img tags in there that don't have any width so I need to find those and add a width attribute via inline CSS to those img tags.

They look like this:

`<img class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-31kj" src="someimage.jpg" alt="">`

`<img class="alignleft large-medium wp-image-3154" src="someimage.jpg" alt="">`

How can I find these img tags and add this to them:

`style="width:100%"`

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Already doing the above using jquery but its not reliable:

```
$(".img").each(function() {  
   var imgWidth = $(this).width();
   if (imgWidth == 0){
       $(this).css('width','100%');

   }
  });
```

Comment: Do this using javascript `querySelectorAll('img').forEach()` add your checks inside the foreach & apply the styling you want.

Comment: @ahmad, I am already using javascript but it fails sometimes and server side code is far more reliable than client side.

Comment: Pull the `img` with a parser, check for a `width` attribute, if not present add one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: @user3783243 would a parser work with stuff that comes from MYSQL database?!

Comment: @JamesJuanjie Yes, just load it as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with simple, self-explanatory css code

```
img:not([width]) {
   width:100%;
}
```

Just target img tags that does not have `width` property

Comment: This does not target images that does have only `width` set using inline CSS.

Comment: This actually works but its not PHP. how reliable is this method?

Comment: @JamesJuanjie Are you asking if you can rely on css? Pretty much.

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll` to get all `img` elements with `class` attribute containing `wp-image` and set the style.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[class*=wp-image]").forEach(function(img) {
  img.style.width = "100%";
});
```

```html
<img src="https://duckduckgo.com/favicon.ico" class="wp-image-foo">
<img src="https://google.com/favicon.ico" class="wp-image-bar">
```

---

If you want to select all images without `width` attribute or CSS property, use this:

```js
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  var img = imgs[i];
  if (img.style.width == "" && img.attributes.width === undefined)
    img.style.width = "100%";
}
```

```html
<img src="https://duckduckgo.com/favicon.ico" class="wp-image-foo">
<img src="https://google.com/favicon.ico" class="wp-image-bar">
<img width=50 src="https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico" class="wp-image-bar">
```

Comment: @JamesJuanjie please view edit in my answer (the second code snippet)